# GCP Microsoft SQL Server XA Transactions support

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql, xa

I've created a SQL Server 2019 Standard instance in my account.

I am trying to enable XA Transactions (Technical requirement) following this Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-ver16

I need to use the next sp -> `sp_sqljdbc_xa_install` but
[image: Google about user permissions]

And it's true, I have no permissions in the `master` database ->

> SQL Error [262] [S0001]:
> CREATE SYNONYM permission denied in database 'master'.

Is it possible to enable XA transactions in SQL Server 2019 Standard managed instance with GCP?

I've been able to enable it in a hosted SQL server with superuser permission without any problem.

Comment: It would be very surprising indeed if this was possible on anything that's not a server you manage entirely on your own -- there are a lot of moving parts here, including (apparently) a dependency on Windows. A cloud provider could not reasonably offer this without giving you your own machine as well, and at that point you may as well manage that yourself. What you could do is ask Google directly if XA support is something they can even potentially enable; this isn't something they'd want to do customers themselves (at least not by following those docs).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will contact with Google.